openwrt shell script to read incoming raw hex data on device and process it
--
Hello!
I have a device sending periodically 8 bytes in hex, starting with 'AA' ending with 'BB' on rs485 lines (no carriage return, no line feed). I received it on my modem running a Openwrt os. This data must be sent on a MQTT broker using mosquitto.
The best would be to scan /dev/rs485 device, wait until an hex message arrives, then stop listening and save the raw message in a variable, and then send it with

mosquitto_pub -m {"data":"raw hex message here"}

I cannont send a file to broker. Broker can only read json.
I struggling to read the data properly the data. The only solution I know is to cat /dev/rs485 to a file, read the file with hexdump and pipe it into a variable.
This is not a short way and I might conflicts with reading/writting simultaneously.
Moreover hexdump displays '1A' instead of 'A1' for example.
Please do you know how to make that work?
Unfortunately, I am not used to scripts and I discover Openwrt.
Thank you very much for your help!

There may be an option to hexdump that will provide the format you need. Use man hexdump to display usage information. If you're lucky info hexdump (if it works) may have more info or samples. As I believe openWRT is a super-small system, it may not have info or man pages available, so you may have to rely on those commands on a full linux system. The options on a full linux may be more than your openWRT. Good luck

I found a great help for using hexdump here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/756313/how-to-remove-all-but-number-from-hexdump-output

I achieve the full transmission device to broker. But the reading of /dev/rs485 is really unstable. cat /dev/rs485 sometimes works, simetimes doesn't

Glad you're making progress. I recommend you post a new question with a [mcve]. Readers will need to be able to copy/paste code into their environment so they can see the issue for themselves. Good luck.

"Moreover hexdump displays '1A' instead of 'A1' for example." - Then what is displayed is the correct byte value, rather than what you assume/expect. There is no swapping of nibbles (or halves of a byte) by a UART or display software. You may be confused about what is endian byte-order.

"But the reading of /dev/rs485 is really unstable" - You need to pay attention to the termios settings, e.g. using the stty command. If you expect "raw hex messages" then you need to use raw rather than cooked mode.
